# Play Framework: JDBC driver class disappears after reload

Tags: scala, jdbc, classloader, playframework-2.2

I load a JDBC driver class using `Class.forName("org.h2.Driver")` in my `Global` object. (The reason for this is because I am accessing *two* databases, which use different JDBC drivers, and one of them is not configured in my `application.conf` file.)

However, when I change a source file in my project (which makes Play recompile and reload the project), I get the following runtime error in my Global object:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:h2:mem:...
```

This doesn't happen the first time the application is run, only after a reload.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to add a config for my second database in `application.conf`, and obtain it by calling the overloaded `getConnection` and `withConnection` methods in `DB` which take a database name as an argument. Then I could remove `Class.forName`, which solved the problem.

Comment: We defined two configurations in our conf and then invokec them by passing right configuration name to JPA.em("configurationName").

Comment: Yes, I forgot that not everyone uses the low-level DB plugin directly.